# AIML Map returns unknown for values in my map

Tags: dictionary, set, aiml

I have a set of classes and a map list of answers and when the answer exists it returns an unknown error.
UDC CODE

```
<category>
    <pattern>^<set>courses</set>^</pattern>
    <that>WHAT HAS BEEN YOUR FAVORITE COURSE</that>
    <template><map name = "coursesgood"><star/></map></template>
</category>
<category>
    <pattern>*</pattern>
    <that>WHAT HAS BEEN YOUR FAVORITE COURSE</that>
    <template>What was another course that you enjoyed?</template>
</category>
```

MAP CODE

```
[
["Web", "What is your favorite programing language?"],
["Networking", "Do you enjoy setting up computer networks?"],
["Security", "Do you enjoy Interacting with people?"],
["Scripting", "Do you enjoy interacting with people"],
["Programing", "What is your favorite programing language"],
["Project", "Do you enjoy Interacting with people??"],
["Calculus", "What is you favorite programing language?"],
["Discreet", "What is your favorite programing language?"],
["Data", "Have you considered becoming a Database Administrator?"],
["Software", "What is your favorite programing language?"],
["Algorithms", "What is your favorite programing language?"],
["Quality", "Have you considered becoming a  Software Quality Assurer?"],
["IT", "Do you enjoy Interacting with people?"]
]
```

SET CODE

```
[["Web"], ["Project"], ["Discreet"], ["Data"], ["Software"], ["Quality"], ["IT"], ["Networking"], ["Security"], ["Scripting"], ["Programing"], ["Calculus"], ["Algorithms"]]
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are checking the wrong wildcard in your pattern. Your pattern consists of 3 wildcards:

1. anything that is said before the course name
2. the course name
3. anything that is said after the course name.

You need to check the second wildcard's value rather than the first.

```
<category>
    <pattern>^ <set>courses</set> ^</pattern>
    <that>WHAT HAS BEEN YOUR FAVORITE COURSE</that>
    <template><map name="coursesgood"><star index="2"/></map></template>
</category>
```